# Design pattern to separate messages from actual process

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am having a C# application to sync data between PC and palm devices.
There are codes written like below:

```
  showMessage("synchronizing Table1");

  Sync(destTable1,sourceTable1);

  Sync(destTable2,sourceTable2);

  showMessage("synchronizing Table2");
  // more code
```

How do I separate the actual process of synchronizing from displaying message?
Which design pattern to follow?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the sync process on a separate thread and inform the main thread of the progress. The main thread displays messages.

You can obtain this behavior using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class that has all the feature ready.

Comment: I need to know design pattern to decouple both part.
Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Seems an Observer pattern: the main thread is the subscriber to the events of the sync process thread